Filter is not working in PowerBI React app
Filter is not working in PowerBI React app.
The report loads/renders fine.
However the column (name) added to basicFilter shows in visual with a warning.
And it does not filter.

Whatever values I enter for table and column in filter it has same result.
The data source for the PowerBI report is Azure delta table.
Tried with various names but it seems name and column is not picked up.
Tried adding updateFilter but to no avail.
(window as any).report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [basicFilter]);

Any suggestions ?
const basicFilter: IBasicFilter = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
  target: {
    table: "people",
    column: "name"
  },
  operator: "In",
  values: ["paul", "mike"],
  filterType: 1 // pbi.models.FilterType.BasicFilter
}

return (<div className="neo-widget__content">
  <div className="neo-widget__header">
    <div className="neo-widget__header-left">
      <span className="neo-icon-agents"></span>
      <h4>Power BI Report</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="neo-widget__body">
    <div className="container">
      <h3><b>People</b></h3>
      <PowerBIEmbed
        embedConfig={{
          type: 'report',
          id: reportId,
          embedUrl: ebdUrl,
          accessToken: tkn,
          tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
          filters: [basicFilter],
          settings: {
            panes: {
              filters: {
                expanded: false,
                visible: true
              }
            },
          }
        }}

        eventHandlers={
          new Map([
            ['loaded', async function () {
              console.log('Report loaded');
            }],
            ['rendered', function () { console.log('Report rendered'); }],
            ['error', function (event) { console.log(event.detail); }],
            ['visualClicked', () => console.log('visual clicked')],
            ['pageChanged', (event) => console.log(event)],
          ])
        }
        cssClassName={"Embed-container"}
        getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
          (window as any).report = embeddedReport;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);


Took a while to figure out.
Turns out the table value in filter obj was incorrect.
I had it set to people but it should include Azure/Databricks catalog-name, db-name and table-name.
"`<catalog-name> <database-name> <table-name>`"

Note: the syntax has back-ticks and spaces.
So in my case.
const basicFilter: IBasicFilter = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
  target: {
    table: "`gary_catalog default people`",
    column: "name"
  },
  operator: "In",
  values: ["paul", "mike"],
  filterType: 1 // pbi.models.FilterType.BasicFilter
}

